# Why are logarithms not defined for negatives bases?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Why isn't the operation $\log_{-2}( -8)$ defined if $(-2)^3 =-8$?

Comment: In my opinion, it is just a general conviction, like the fact that when graphing root functions we do not consider the negative solution. If you think about it, negative bases would bring up many complications, and their definition would be more complex

Comment: They are,  given that you look on the complex logarithm.